# Can we make this snippet groovier?

Tags: groovy, refactoring, code-snippets

are there any improvements where i can improve this code? Maybe there are some groovy language features? This snippet flattens a xml file to: node/node/node

```
def root = new XmlParser().parse("src/your_xml.xml")

root.depthFirst().each { n ->
    def name = n.name()
    while(n?.parent()){
        name = "${n?.parent()?.name()}/${name}";
        n = n?.parent()
    }
    println name
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might refactor the code to use a more functional style.

```
def x = """
<test>
    <test1>
        <test2/>
    </test1>
    <test2>
        <test3/>
        <test4>
            <test5/>
        </test4>
    </test2>
</test>
""".trim()

def root = new XmlParser().parseText(x)

def nodePath(node) {
    node.parent() ? "${nodePath(node.parent())}/${node.name()}" : node.name()
}

root.depthFirst().each {
    println nodePath(it)
}

assert nodePath(root.test2[0].test4[0].test5[0]) == "test/test2/test4/test5"
```

Answer (score 1):

-- Edit: Ignore me, I'm wrong [see comments] (not the last line though);

I suspect you can write (but I could be wrong, I have no experience with this language)

```
while(n = n?.parent()){
```

But honestly; don't go with something that is cool, go with something that is readable.

Comment: +1 on the "don't go with something cool, go with something readable"

Comment: You're definitely right. I am also for readable code! Maybe you just get me wrong, i searched for some groovy features i can use. that maybe makes this code more readable. Thanks :)

Comment: For your code: This isn't possible, only with an do while, buts that not a feature in groovy afaik